# how to generate a matrix of unknown size through for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

The code

```
conf=ones(103,1);  
f=conf;  
for k=1:103  
    f(k:k+1)=1i;  
    conf=f.*conf;  
    p(k,:)=conf;  
end
```

Now I actually want to record the result of each iteration in matrix `p`.  So that I can use this product result later in my program.
final `p` matrix could be like

`[i i 1 1 1 1 1...

   i -1 i 1 1 1 1.....

   i -i -1 i 1 1 1.....

   so on]`.

Comment: I thought I understood what you were trying to do, but I realized it is not clear! Post what the final array should look like for a smaller example - your code does not make much sense....

Comment: I want to replace the 1s in 'conf' with 'i' (imaginary unit) with every iteration. Then multiply this with 'conf' and get a product. Now I want to form a matrix of this product values, so that i could use these values further.

Comment: what doesn't make any sense is that `p=f.*conf;` is *always* going to be equal to the statement `p=f` since `conf=1` (or a vector of 1s).

Comment: oopps ok got it. what a silly mistake.let me try again.

Comment: but still the same error `matrix dimensions must agree` is coming. how to sort this out.

Comment: can you post the changes you made to your question? Thing is I can find a way to change your code so it won't generate an error message, but that doesn't mean that it'll do what *you* want!

Comment: I edited the question please check it. I just want to record the result of each iteration in matrix 'p'. and yaa i preallocated 'p'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did all the hard fixes already. I *think* what you want is:

```
conf=ones(103,1);  
f=conf;  
for k=1:102         % <--- reduced this because otherwise f(k:k+1) attempts to 
                    %      index beyond the size of f
    f(k:k+1)=1i;  
    conf=f.*conf;  
    p(k,:)=conf;  
end
p(103,:)=1i;
```

I would check the results for a smaller array. For instance if I run the following smaller version of the above (as a test)

```
conf=ones(5,1);  
f=conf;  
for k=1:4 
    f(k:k+1)=1i;  
    conf=f.*conf;  
    p(k,:)=conf;  
end
p(5,:)=1i;
```

I get

```
>> real(p)

ans =

     0     0     1     1     1
    -1    -1     0     1     1
     0     0    -1     0     1
     1     1     0    -1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

and

```
>> imag(p)

ans =

     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
    -1    -1     0     1     0
     0     0    -1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```